# Is there a difference between writing 'button.click' in code and clicking the button, in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, button, buttonclick

I have a problem. When I click on the buttons used interface is working properly, I want to do this work automatically using xxx.click but it does not work properly. What is the difference between?

```
if pos(hexFileVersion, currentFWVersion) = 0 then
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Versions are different from each other, updating...');
  btnReset.Click;
  sleep(500);
  btnCaptureTarget.Click;
  sleep(500);
  BProgram.Click;
  sleep(200);
  BResetLIA.Click;
end;
```

Comment: between ... **and** ...?

Comment: Impossible to say. Click method works fine. You didn't say what goes wrong, what you expect etc. Those Sleeps seem bogus.

Comment: between writing 'xxx.click' and the click of the button...

Comment: Rather use actions. In each action's `OnExecute` event method you write a code to perform and bind those actions to button's `Action` property. To execute an action manually you just call `TAction.Execute`. It won't resolve your problem or answer this question but it could help you to do things in a proper way.

Comment: @Muammer: No, not really (except for the obvious things, like xxx.click happening automatically, while a real click usually is done by the user).

Comment: "does not work properly" is not a problem description unless you explain what "does not work properly" means. If you don't understand why not, try calling your auto repair shop and saying "My car does not work properly. What's wrong with it? And how much will it cost to fix?" and see if they're willing to give you a cost and time estimate.

Answer (score 7):

If you have code in a click handler that needs to be called elsewhere then the correct approach would be to refactor that work into separate methods.  Programatically clicking buttons as a means to fire event handlers as a means to execute code is just poor practice.  As others have noted, the method in your question should work equivalently but it is a style of programming that should really be avoided.

For example, if you have :

```
procedure TForm1.btnResetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
  //  here some actions are taken
  //
  //
end;
```

you can refactor into :

```
procedure TForm1.DoReset;
begin
  //
  //  here some actions are taken
  //
  //
end;

procedure TForm1.btnResetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoReset;
end;
```

this way, if you need to `DoReset` outside the context of the click handler you can just write :

```
if pos(hexFileVersion, currentFWVersion) = 0 then begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Versions are different from each other, updating...');
  DoReset;      
  DoCaptureTarget;      
  DoBProgram;
  DoBResetLIA;    
end;
```

User interface event handlers, as a general rule, should be *very* lightweight - they should have as little code as possible in them.  If business logic starts creeping into them it should be a strong sign that you need to tidy them up.

Comment: One big reason to move your handler logic into separate functions/classes is unit testing. You can test your GUI logic without actually using the GUI...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what "does not work properly" in your case.

`btnReset.Click` calls `OnClick()` or `OnExecute()` if action is associated with this Button.

But when you click by mouse then for example also `onMouseDown` and `OnMouseUp` can fire if assigned.

```
procedure TControl.Click;
begin
  { Call OnClick if assigned and not equal to associated action's OnExecute.
    If associated action's OnExecute assigned then call it, otherwise, call
    OnClick. }
  if Assigned(FOnClick) and (Action <> nil) and (@FOnClick <> @Action.OnExecute) then
    FOnClick(Self)
  else if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) and (ActionLink <> nil) then
    ActionLink.Execute(Self)
  else if Assigned(FOnClick) then
    FOnClick(Self);
end;
```

Also try to insert `Application.ProcessMessages;` after each `.Click`

```
btnReset.Click;
Application.ProcessMessages;

sleep(500);

btnCaptureTarget.Click;
Application.ProcessMessages;

sleep(500);

BProgram.Click;
Application.ProcessMessages;

sleep(200);

BResetLIA.Click;
```

Comment: But this answer has a number of good parts in it, like the point made about `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseUp`.

Comment: ProcessMessages make this method likely to be reentrant. Especially with the bogus sleeps.

Comment: @JerryDodge I agree with all of you about bad design and `ProcessMessges` and reentering (you can avoid this using for example flag variable and `try .. finally`). BUT considering the question and these SLEEPS I guess the topic starter tries to wait for some changes (I guess with GUI) which have to occur after `btnReset.Click` and before `btnCaptureTarget.Click`. But using SLEEP doesn't help here. Because If the USER clicks on these two buttons with mouse then GUI messages are processed between these two events but if you call `.Click` then you can use `ProcessMessages` to emulate this.